# Is google endpoints hipaa compliance

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, hipaa

I'm not sure about this, i think i can use it for a app that needs hipaa compliance, because the nginx container is running on GKE or GCE and this services are hipaa compliance. Or is it not compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product Manager here.

Endpoints is not yet on Google's official list of HIPAA compliant products (available [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/#covered-products)).

We not believe it is non-compliant, but it has not yet gone through the certification process (and we have a few products ahead of it in the queue). I'd love to bump it up in the queue; feel free to email me (ciruli at google dot com) and I will let the certification team know about the request. I can't promise a schedule or timeframe, but customer input certainly helps.